# Matplotlib: Add value on bar with cumulative histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I created the following histogram with matplotlib. How do I add percentages on the bars without having to create a new dataframe with the percentages themselves?

```
x = df1 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.hist(x['tx'],range=[0,11],cumulative=True, density=True, bins=np.arange(11)+ 0.7,color='dimgray',edgecolor='white',width=0.6)
plt.xticks(range(11))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, step=0.1))

ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter(xmax=1))


ax.grid(linestyle='-', linewidth='0.4', color='grey')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function plt.text(x,y,s) to print a text on a plot, where x and y are the position of the text string s.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html

Here is how it would work in your example:

```
array = np.random.randint(0, 11, 50)
values, x_pos, _ = plt.hist(array,range=[0,11],cumulative=True, density=True, bins=np.arange(11)+ 0.7,color='dimgray',edgecolor='white',width=0.6)
plt.xticks(range(11))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, step=0.1))

[plt.text(x_, val, "{0:.1f} %".format(val *100)) for x_, val in zip(x_pos, values)]
```

[image]

For the text format and to choose the number of decimals to show, or if you want to convert to percentage, you can get more information on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-formatting-in-python/

Comment: Hey Lio, thanks very much!

I am trying to understand the syntax of your code. As I am a total Python beginner, I don't really get where to modify the position of the values. And how to you call that expression that is in brackets on the bottom?

Comment: no problem, so maybe zip(x1, x2) allows you to iterate over two elements in a single loop. Then the syntax "".format() is called a fomat specifier and allows you to specifiy the value you want to put in the string object. You can check the link in the answer to dicover more on its usage. Finally the brackets is just a 'list comprehension' which is very common in python to create a list from a for loop, or to do a loop in a single line.